# Mongo DB - Second Level Search - elemMatch

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am trying to fetch all records (and count of all records) for a structure like the following,

```
{
  id: 1,
  level1: {
    level2: 
      [
        {
          field1:value1; 
        },
        {
          field1:value1; 
        },
      ]
  }
},
{
      id: 2,
      level1: {
        level2: 
          [
            {
              field1:null; 
            },
            {
              field1:value1; 
            },
          ]
      }
    }
```

My requirement is to fetch the number of records that have field1 populated (atleast one in level2). I need to say fetch all the ids or the number of such ids.

The query I am using is,

```
db.table.find({}, 
    {
      _id = id,
      value: {
          $elemMatch: {'level1.level2.field1':{$exists: true}}
      }
    }
})
```

Please suggest.

EDIT1: 
This is the question I was trying to ask in the comment. I was unable to elucidate in the comment properly. Hence, editing the question.

```
{
  id: 1,
  level1: {
    level2: 
      [
        {
          field1:value1; 
        },
        {
          field1:value1; 
        },
      ]
  }
},
{
      id: 2,
      level1: {
        level2: 
          [
            {
              field1:value2; 
            },
            {
              field1:value2; 
            },
            {
              field1:value2; 
            }
          ]
      }
    }
    {
      id: 3,
      level1: {
        level2: 
          [
            {
              field1:value1; 
            },
            {
              field1:value1; 
            },
          ]
      }
    }
```

The query we used results in

```
value1: 4
value2: 3
```

I want something like

```
value1: 2 // Once each for documents 1 & 3
value2: 1 // Once for document 2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with the following find query:

```
db.table.find({ "level1.level2" : { $elemMatch: { field1 : {$exists: true} } } }, {})
```

This will return all documents that have a field1 in the "level1.level2" structure.

For your question in the comment, you can use the following aggregation to "I had to return a grouping (and the corresponding count) for the values in field1":

```
db.table.aggregate(
  [
    {
      $unwind: "$level1.level2"
    },
    {
      $match: { "level1.level2.field1" : { $exists: true } }
    },
    {
      $group: {
      _id : "$level1.level2.field1",
      count : {$sum : 1}
      }
    }
  ]
```

UPDATE: For your question "'value1 - 2` At level2, for a document, assume all values will be the same for field1.".
I hope i understand your question correctly, instead of grouping only on the value of field1, i added the document _id as an xtra grouping:

```
db.table.aggregate(
  [
    {
      $unwind: "$level1.level2"
    },
    {
      $match: { 
        "level1.level2.field1" : { $exists: true }
      }
    },
    {
      $group: {
            _id : { id : "$_id", field1: "$level1.level2.field1" },
            count : {$sum : 1}
            }
    }
  ]
);
```

UPDATE2: 
I altered the aggregation and added a extra grouping, the aggregation below gives you the results you want.

```
db.table.aggregate(
  [
    {
      $unwind: "$level1.level2"
    },
    {
      $match: { 
              "level1.level2.field1" : { $exists: true }
            }
    },
    {
      $group: {
                  _id : { id : "$_id", field1: "$level1.level2.field1" }
                  }
    },
    {
      $group: {
                  _id : { id : "$_id.field1"},
                  count : { $sum : 1}
                  }
    }
  ]
);
```

Comment: Thanks. I was wondering if I had to return a grouping (and the corresponding count) for the values in field1, how would I change it?

Comment: I'm sorry if I was not clear with my question. This query would return the following as an output -

`value1 - 3`

What I'm looking for is something like, 

'value1 - 2`

At level2, for a document, assume all values will be the same for field1. But, it should be counted as one entry (though there are more than one loops for field1 in the same document)

Comment: See my updates answer, when it's not correct, please specify the data you want returned

Comment: Updated my answer with an aggregation which gives you the results you are looking for.